# Integrate JQuery steps with ZK framework

Tags: zk, jquery-steps

I am trying to integrate the jQuery plugin "steps" with ZK framework. I am using textboxes and data binding like so:

`<textbox value="@bind(vm.Model.prop.propOfProp)/>"`

I use jQuery steps like so:

```
$("#form").steps({
    bodyTag: "fieldset",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
   onFinishing : function(event,currentIndex) {
            $('.z-button')[0].click();
            return true;
           }
});
```

What I have been trying is to trigger the click event on the ZK button and the event is fired but all the data bindings are ignored. It appears that the "steps" plugin sends the form in a way that zk doesn't like.

I have already tried the exact same form without the plugin and it works.

***How would that be possible if possible ?***

I looked for information about how the plugin sends the forms and if it has influence over the inputs but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery steps plugin can't be integrated to zk in its current state due to the influance it has on the inputs and the formdata itself.If you really need it you will have to change the plugin code or simulate it manually with JavaScript on the client side like I did because its easier. You can find my code here ! [My manual solution!](https://github.com/georgiStoyanov/cobralitasee/blob/master/WebContent/plantilla/js/jsAjustados/form_wizard.js)